# HTML5 dataList and arrayLists in Struts2

Tags: html, arraylist, struts2, iterator, datalist

I have a Struts2 program that I would like to implement auto complete in and have stumbled across the data list tag - a seemingly easy to use functionality that is just what I am looking for. Previous to this I intended on using the struts2-dojo-tag plugin the realized that that plugin is no longer supported with some help from this site.

Since I need my autocomplete to be dynamic I pass a arrayList of varying length into my JSP and intend to iterate over said arrayList to input it into the dataList tag. This is what I have right now:

```
 <s:set var="exampleList" value="exampleList" />
 <p>
  <label>  Enter your favorite guitar player:<br />
     <input type="text" id="favGtrPlayer" list="GtrPlayers">
      <datalist id="GtrPlayers">
         <s:iterator status="stat" value="exampleList">
                 <option value="%{exampleList.next()}">
         </s:iterator>
      </datalist>
   </label> 
 </p>
```

exampleList is successfully transferred from the action to the jsp. I am just getting confused how to properly iterate through it and assign it to an option for the dataList tag.

Thanks in advance for any help you can supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question, this is how I did it:

```
 <input list="browsers" />
 <datalist id="browsers">
      <s:iterator status="stat" value="exampleList">
         <option value=<s:property/> />
      </s:iterator>
 </datalist>
```

This iterates through my list and adds each entry in the list to an autocomplete menu.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<label>  Enter your favorite guitar player:<br />
 <input type="text" id="favGtrPlayer" list="GtrPlayers">
   <s:iterator status="stat" value="exampleList">
             <option value="exampleList.id">  //use pojo class variable.`private String id`
   </s:iterator>
 </datalist>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I found a simpler solution but I appreciate the effort

Answer (score 0):

```
 <datalist id="GtrPlayers">
         <s:iterator status="stat" value="exampleList">
                 <option value="%{exampleList.next()}">
         </s:iterator>
      </datalist>
```

In  `<option value="%{exampleList.next()}">`>

you shoud use `<option value="<s:property value="PropertyName"/> />`

Enter your `PropertyName` which you want to display